# Toggle code which doesn't appear work in any version of IE?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have been working on a website over the past few days and it utilises a toggle feature to show/hide some information.

I put together the following piece of jQuery and it seems to do the job perfectly fine in every other browser but IE and to put it simply i'm stumped.

I have tried outputting to the console but its as if IE just ignores the whole thing as there is never any output, anyway i'm curious as to whats going on here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript ">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".description_more").click(function(){
         var i=this.id;
         if($(this).html()=='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i> Show more information'){
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i> Hide information');
            $('#desc_'+i).toggle();
         }else{
            $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i> Show more information');
            $('#desc_'+i).toggle();
         }
      });               
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Mathing HTML in if conditions is probably the worst idea ever, the browser can return just about anything, and not neccessarely what you wrote, and even a small space would f*ck up the result !

Comment: Try something more like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Lfd85/1/**

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to test for the use of `fa-arrow-circle-down` or `fa-arrow-circle-up`, rather than checking the html?

Comment: Works for me. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/QzDcY/show/ Works till IE9. Jsfiddle doesn't support IE8. Otherwise code works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is IE for ya!

```
<script type="text/javascript ">
```

That space after javascript... that's what is breaking it!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Will fix it!  Love you IE!!

Comment: I tested this in IE11.  But the others are right above.  Best to use .addClass("visible") and test for $(this).hasClass("visible") as HTML may change in the future and you forget to change your javacscript code.

Comment: Seems like a combination of this and the fact I had other jQuery scripts starting with <script> rather than <script type="text/javascript"> has caused the issue. All seems to be working as expect now.